# Should I use AutoMapper from ViewModel to Model objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel, automapper

I want to go the way doing all input validation in a viewmodel.

When the database is accessed the viewmodels data must be copied over to the model sent to database.

My concern is that data could be lost because:

- Automapper is wrongly setup for certain scenarios thus properties are not copied over to the model
- Or Automapper is just not suited for every scenario maybe too complex ViewModels

Are my concerns justified or should I not care for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper is totally fine in this scenario I use it extensively for exactly this purpose.  If you are worried about data lose should you not be making use of data annotation validation on the model itself to make sure you have the required data before persisting or calling some other service.

Also the only real way to make completely sure that you dont miss anything using Auotomapper or just manual code mapping is a good set of unit tests.

Comment: Ok validation only on the ViewModel. I have read that the Automapper call should be done in an extra class which serves separation of concern (SOC) not in the mvc Controller. Where do YOU make this call? In the Business Layer?

Comment: You can convert it in the controller pass the viewmodel of to the service layer if you want, or package it as a RequestObject and pass that up.  Then in the service layer use AutoMapper.  Its up to you and how complex your app is.  Do what makes you happy.  You can use DataAnnotation validation with no view model like this https://gist.github.com/1663112

Comment: "...pass the viewmodel of to the service layer if you want..." As the viewmodel is annotated with attributes belonging to MVC namespace I think its not a good idea to couple my service layer to MVC. Thanks for all.

Comment: @Elisa the annotation sit in System.ComponentModel.DataAnotations only remote validations are part of MVC.  This means that its fine to pass these models around.  People may argue that its not valid from a conceptual standpoint, one pattern would be to make request and response objects that your service layer take and map your viewmodel to that first.

Comment: @Elisa: I am on the same page with you Elisa. I also think that having service layer working only on the Model and independent of ViewModel is better. I am also looking for a good way to transfer data from Model to ViewModel and vice-versa. All people around are using AutoMapper... but I wanted to use something that I know what I am doing :|

Answer (score 0):

> My concern is that data could be lost because:          Automapper is
>   wrongly setup for certain scenarios thus properties are not copied
>   over to the model     Or Automapper is just not suited for every scenario
>   maybe too complex ViewModels
>
> I think it is unlikely that you will loose data. For complex 
>   viewModels you can choose to set specific properties manually which 
>   are not copied over by Automapper. As suggested by @feanz good Unit 
>   Test will provide you required assurance.**